# How to create a separate df after applying groupby?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df as follows:

```
Product Step
1   1
1   3
1   6
1   6
1   8
1   1
1   4
2   2
2   4
2   8
2   8
2   3
2   1
3   1
3   3
3   6
3   6
3   8
3   1
3   4
```

What I would like to do is to:

1. For each `Product`, every `Step` must be grabbed and the order must not be changed, that is, if we look at Product 1, after Step 8, there is a 1 coming and that 1 must be after 8 only. So, the expected output for product 1 and product 3 should be of the order: 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4; for the product 2 it must be: 2, 4, 8, 3, 1.

**Update:**
Here, I only want one value of 6 for product 1 and 3, since in the main df both the 6 next to each other, but both the values of 1 must be present since they are not next to each other.

2. Once the first step is done, the products with the same Steps must be grouped together into a new df (in the below example: Product 1 and 3 have same Steps, so they must be grouped together)

**What I have done:**

```
import pandas as pd
sid = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby('Product').apply(lambda x: x['Step'].unique())).reset_index()
```

But it is yielding a result like:

```
    Product 0
0   1   [1 3 6 8 4]
1   2   [2 4 8 3 1]
2   3   [1 3 6 8 4]
```

which is not the result I want. I would like the value for the first and third product to be [1 3 6 8 1 4].

Comment: The ordering is really  `1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 1, 4`, but you seem to state it is `1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4`. Does this mean you would treat 2 Products with  `1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4` and  `1, 3, 6, 6, 8, 1, 4` as belonging to the same group?

Comment: yes, they both must belong to the same group. Ideally, since both the 6s are next to each other, I would only like to choose one of them, but since both the 1s are not next to each other, both of them must be separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC Create the Newkey by using `cumsum` and `diff`

```
df['Newkey']=df.groupby('Product').Step.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
df.drop_duplicates(['Product','Newkey'],inplace=True)
s=df.groupby('Product').Step.apply(tuple)
s.reset_index().groupby('Step').Product.apply(list)
Step
(1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4)    [1, 3]
(2, 4, 8, 3, 1)          [2]
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` preservers the order of rows within a group, so there isn't much need to worry about the rows shifting.

A straightforward, but not greatly performant, solution would be to `apply(tuple)`, since they are hashable allowing you to group on them to see which Products are identical. `form_seq` will make it so that consecutive values only appear once in the list of steps before forming the tuple.

```
def form_seq(x):
    x = x[x != x.shift()]
    return tuple(x)

s = df.groupby('Product').Step.apply(form_seq)
s.groupby(s).groups

#{(1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4): Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64', name='Product'),
# (2, 4, 8, 3, 1): Int64Index([2], dtype='int64', name='Product')}
```

Or if you'd like a DataFrame:

```
s.reset_index().groupby('Step').Product.apply(list)
#Step
#(1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4)    [1, 3]
#(2, 4, 8, 3, 1)          [2]
#Name: Product, dtype: object
```

The values of that dictionary are the groupings of products that share the step sequence (given by the dictionary keys). Products 1 and 3 are grouped together by the step sequence `1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 4`.

Answer (score 0):

Another very similar way:

```
df_no_dups=df[df.shift()!=df].dropna(how='all').ffill()
df_no_dups_grouped=df_no_dups.groupby('Product')['Step'].apply(list)
```